# Android studio shortcut for French keyboard

Tags: android-studio, shortcut, azerty-keyboard

I'm a beginner on Android development, and I can't find the shortcuts for french keyboards (stupid AZERTY). Is there a place where I can find them?
I'm searching especially the shortcuts to comment/uncomment line and block of code.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think it's same as QWERTY keyboard shortcut. Try with `Ctrl + /` to comment or uncomment, for block comments select the part of code and use `Ctrl + Shift + /`

Comment: I tried already those shortcuts but they don't work on my computer. Anyway, I changed the shortcuts going in file/settings/keymap, it did the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

On file/settings/keymap, we can easily custom the shortcuts we want.

Answer (score 0):

In azerty french keyboard, initially short cut are : for single line comment `command + /` or `command + NumPad` and for the block comment `command + shift + /` or `command + shift + NumPad` but if you have a mac laptop you don't have NumPad key and you can't type `/` because you need shift to do it otherwise it will type `:`

The solution is to go in android studio preference -> Keymap -> Main menu -> Code -> Folding -> Comment with Line / Comment with block. Or you can use the search-bar and type comment then you can modifie your shortcut.